# Is there a way in JQuery to find if a sibling of an input has a given css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span>
    <input name="" autocomplete="off" label="" class="form-control mandatory field-mandatory" placeholder="">   
    <span class="goog-combobox-button"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" id="ctl00_cntMainBody_OBJECT_ONE__PMLookupField" name="ctl00_cntMainBody_OBJECT_ONE__PMLookupField">
</span>
```

I would like to find out if there is a way, using jQuery, to find if the **input** above the one with **id=ctl00_cntMainBody_OBJECT_ONE__PMLookupField** has a css class **field-mandatory**. There are many spans on the page with similar to this one. I am working within the existing structure of html with no option to change. Since the input has no id the only way to locate it is by using the input below it that has an id.

Comment: I think your invalid results might be because your `<span class="goog-combobox-button"/>` is invalid HTML - you can't have self closing span tags

Answer (score 0):

Find each hidden input and target the sibling you want :-

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
  var inputAbove = $(this).siblings('input.field-mandatory');
  // DO SOMETHING
});
```